# JFrame graphics ignores the first few renders

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

Here is a minimal code to see the bug:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main1 extends JFrame {
    static Main1 main;
    public Main1() {
        super("app");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main = new Main1();
        main.setBounds(300, 300, 800, 500);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = main.getGraphics();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

If i use 100 in the "for" cycle, the frame appears not to be colored, but 200 loops is enough to color it.

I want to make an application where frames change rarely, but this feature ruins the quality of code because I have to make a number of dummy frames.

Comment: This is not how you do Swing graphics. Getting a Graphics object by calling `.getGraphics()` on a component gives you a short-lived unstable and sometimes null object. Instead paint within a JPanel's paintComponent method using the Graphics object given by the JVM as per the tutorials.

Comment: Also, if all you want to do is to set the background color of the JFrame, then simply call `setBackground(...)` on its contentPane in the constructor and you're set.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  +1 for the minimal, reproducible example, that really helps us.  I believe the Swing tutorial on [custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) could be of use to you.  Also, I see that you refer to the for loop iterations as "frames."  Note that a for loop will not result in distinct "frames."  It runs way too fast for that.  You would need to use a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) in order to make any animation.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main = new Main1();
    main.setBounds(300, 300, 800, 500);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
    Graphics g = main.getGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
    }
}
```

This is not how you do Swing graphics. Getting a Graphics object by calling .getGraphics() on a component gives you a short-lived unstable and sometimes null object. For instance, it takes some time for the created JFrame to render, and if you call `getGraphics()` and try to use it prior to rendering, the object may be null, and certainly won't wokr.

Instead paint within a JPanel's paintComponent method using the Graphics object given by the JVM as per the tutorials:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    public MainPanel {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500)));
        setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0)); // if you just want to set background
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        // use g here do do your drawing
    }

}
```

and then use it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

And yes, if you want to drive a simple animation, use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to help drive it like so:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public MainPanel {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500)));
        setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0)); // if you just want to set background
        
        // timer code:
        int timerDelay = 15;
        new Timer(timerDelay, ()-> {
            x += 4;
            y += 4;
            repaint();
        }).start();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        // use g here do do your drawing
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

}
```